# error: could not build Objective-C module 'agora_rtc_engine'

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

Following up on the repo https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Flutter-Quickstart

Unable to build the project on macOS with the following spec

```
Flutter 2.2.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision d79295af24 (10 days ago) • 2021-06-11 08:56:01 -0700
Engine • revision 91c9fc8fe0
Tools • Dart 2.13.3
```

Here is the full error stack

```
/.../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-3.3.3/ios/Classes/Base/AgoraRtcEngineKit.h:9:9: error: 'AgoraRtcKit/AgoraRtcEngineKit.h' file not found
#import <AgoraRtcKit/AgoraRtcEngineKit.h>
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'agora_rtc_engine'
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Analyzing workspace
note: Constructing build description
note: Build preparation complete
/.../Agora-Flutter-Quickstart/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target
'AgoraRtcEngine_iOS' from project 'Pods')
/.../Agora-Flutter-Quickstart/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Flutter'
from project 'Pods')
```

Answer (score 0):

I"m not sure if this solution works for others, but this is what worked for me

In here https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Flutter-Quickstart/blob/master/pubspec.yaml#L21:L23

Changed Agora RTC engine version and permission handler to

```
  agora_rtc_engine: ^4.0.1
  permission_handler: ^6.0.1
```

And do the following

- Remove ios/Podfile.lock
- Remove Pods folder
- cd ios > `pod install or pod install --repo-update`
- Remove pubspec.lock
- Remove build folder
- Run `flutter pub get`

If this still does not work

```
rm -rf /YourUserPath/.pub-cache
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
rm ios/Podfile
rm ios/Podfile.lock
rm pubspec.lock
rm -rf ios/Pods
rm -rf ios/Runner.xcworkspace
flutter clean
flutter build ios
flutter clean
flutter run
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution according [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/128535):

1. Quit Xcode.
2. Delete project's temp files located at
   ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
3. Delete ProjectName.xcworkspace
4. Delete Podfile.lock file and Pods folder
5. Run pod install.
6. Open the newly created ProjectName.xcworkspace file and build.